# Laravel composer installation Error - The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I'm facing some issues in during installation of laravel 5.2, when i run composer setup.exe then i get these errors.

The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly:
C:\xampp\php\php.exe

The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini

A setting in your php.ini could be causing the problem: Either the 'extension_dir' value is incorrect or the dll does not exist.

Program Output:
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_oci8_12c.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
 in Unknown on line 0
Warning: Module 'openssl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Please help me for fixing these errors. Thanks

my system is 64-bit

Comment: have you tried installing PHP again? or XAMPP

Comment: i have already installed my xamp now just installing composer.